# Which metrics to set for API?

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I would like to set the following metrics to my API, how do I do that?
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9143382#zippy=%2Cpage-screen
"Entrances","Exits","Views"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which API you are using. You can add more detail on the question.

If you are using GA4 and want to retrieve data from API

You should use the "Google Analytics Data API (GA4)
"

Here is the documentation about all the dimension and metrics available.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

Comment: I used Google Analytics Data API (PHP client library)
I refer to 'API dimensions & metrics', but couldn't find any metrics for the items I showed.

Comment: I guess `views` is `screenPageViews`. `Entrance` should be `landing page`. Not sure about `Exits`. Can you point out where you see these 3 metrics in the report?

Comment: Thank you reposnose messgae.
I want to get the metricsga:uniquePageviews,ga:entrances,ga:exitRate of ReportingAPI(UA) also with DataAPI(GA4).
But I couldn't find them in 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4-dims-mets

Comment: There are some different between UA and GA4. Some metrics we used to have in UA might not be available in GA4. If the metric you are looking for are not in the document. (Also can not find in the GA4 report. It might not be show up in the future). But Data API is still changing, it might add the metric and dimension after.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it is still not supported via API, I am using JAVA version of this API & created an issue here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/9279

But you can generate such report using official dashboard as mentioned here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11080047

Here is the list of currently supported metrics & dimensions (via data API):
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema